# setting up a webserver on Monodroid

Tags: webserver, xamarin.android, xamarin

I have to show few offline pages done in MVC. I have the data in SiqoDB on phone. The problem is i need some webserver that will host these offline MVC pages on the phone and fetch data from the db. Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for application or for a library to build the server with Xamarin.Android? For a library I can offer our SecureBlackbox, namely its [HTTPBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-https.php) package that contains components for building an HTTP/HTTPS server. These components work on Xamarin.Android .